# ELMAH for asp.net core

Tags: azure, web-applications, asp.net-core, elmah

I am working on asp.net core webapp hosted on azure and I want to write my Elmah logs to my azure table storage .Many of the examples I looked into are using "API_KEY" and "logbucketId" but I am not sure what they are.
For instance as per elmah docs here https://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-aspnet-core/

```
app.UseElmahIo(
    "API_KEY", 
    new Guid("LOG_ID"),
```

After installing nuget package, I don't see any API_KEY or LogBucketId in my `appsettings.json` file.

Where I can find my API_KEY and LogBucket_Id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ELMAH doesn't work with ASP.NET Core, since ASP.NET Core doesn't work with HttpModules and HttpHandlers (ELMAH stands for Error Logging Modules And Handlers). ASP.NET Core does include a new (pre-release) diagnostic tool called ELM (Error Logging Middleware - creative, right?). You can find its source and samples here:
https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/release/1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Elm

Another option similar to ELMAH (and ELM) but with more capabilities is Glimpse:
http://getglimpse.com/

I realize neither of these directly answers your question but hopefully you'll find one or both of these alternative tools useful.

Comment: FYI, both links are down

Comment: Not sure what's up with Glimpse but you can find the Elm stuff here: https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/release/1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Elm

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore supports `.net core` now.

It is not based on `Modules` or `Handlers`, but `Middleware`.

It works fine although still limited.

The `async` calls are not being used at the moment. But it is quite extensible.

Answer (score 3):

You can check ELMAH port to Net.Core version

https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore

Make sure it is matching your expectation before you use it.

Note: This new extension is in development and doesn't support all Elmah features.

Answer (score 0):

ELMAH doesn't support ASP.NET Core. The documentation you are linking to is from [elmah.io](https://elmah.io). While they have similar names and elmah.io uses ELMAH for some of its integrations, they don't share code or documentation.